# The task in Celery is being passed from Celery Beats to Workers, and is being received there but the task is not being executed. I am using Django

Tags: python, django, celery, scheduled-tasks

Pretty much the title. The task is being passed and received properly but isn't getting executed. So I just kept a simple print statement, it still didn't execute.

What I did notice was, in the admin interface, the task is being set as type 'custom' instead of 'registered' although it has same name as that of the registered task I am trying to execute. Am I missing something?

[Celery config in settings.py] `ed_task def daily_streaks_update(): logger.info("Executing Task")`

[Django admin interface. The task is made custom type although there is already a registered task of same name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZPGEi.png)[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FdebV.png)

[Beat log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6d7QR.png)

[Worker log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Ibvn.png)

What could be the problem?

Tried prompting Chat GPT, Bard and Bing, I had already performed everything they suggested. The documentation was less useful.

Comment: Please include *code*, not *images of code*: see [*Why not upload images of code errors when asking a question*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/67579). [edit] the question and include code fragments with the *code sample* button (`{}`).